# VirtualDocumentRoot & localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, localhost

Currently this is my `httpd-vhosts.config` file

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/Gabri/Sites/%2/%1/build
</VirtualHost>
```

However I would like to have access to `localhost` too to be able to view it on the same network using the computer IP. so I tried this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/Gabri/Sites/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/Gabri/Sites/%2/%1/build
</VirtualHost>
```

but it only directs to `localhost` how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your other site needs another servername. And your DNS must know of it!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/Gabri/Sites/%2/%1/build
    ServerName Something
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I want to keep it flexible I don't want it to have just one name, cause actually under `Sites/` folder there are many sites each in each own directory.

so right now for example I have 

   `Sites/dev/sitesname/build`

I write `sitename.dev` & it works, will it still work like this with your solution?

Comment: Check out this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html

Comment: By the way: maybe you should edit the question so it more reflects what you want!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but doing something like this fixed it for me, the only problem that if I created a new folder under sites I have to go and edit `httpd-vhosts.conf` file again. I hope there is an easier way to do this.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot /Users/<username>/Sites/
  ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias *.dev
  VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/<username>/Sites/dev/%1/build
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias *.wordpress
  VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/<username>/Sites/wordpress/%1/public
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias *.localhost
  VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/<username>/Sites/localhost/%1/www
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a ServerName and ServerAlias in your case you'll probably also need a wildcard :

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/Gabri/Sites/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName default.localhost
   ServerAlias default.localhost * 
   VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/Gabri/Sites/%2/%1/build
</VirtualHost>
```